# "how do i install mariadb version 10.1.37 on ubuntu 18.04"

Tags: mariadb, devops, mariadb-10.1

I am trying to install mariadb version 10.1.37 in ubuntu 18.04, But i am not getting that version.

here is the installation commands i tried.

sudo apt-get update -y

sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 
0xF1656F24C74CD1D8

sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386,ppc64el]http://ftp.utexas.edu/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu xenial main'

sudo apt-get update -y

sudo apt-get install mariadb-server rsync -y

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the names of the contents of the repo the closest version that exists for 18.04 Bionic is

mariadb-server_10.1.41

did you try specifying that version?

[List](http://ftp.utexas.edu/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mariadb-10.1/)

Comment: Filip when i tried above command i am getting version 10.1.43 i tried by specifying version also but no use.